# Submit button showing abnormal behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to submit my form into database.When i clicked on submit button, it did not insert any record and become disabled.
When i see my console, i observed this

The code line

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

changes to

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary disabled" disabled="disabled" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

How can i solve this?

I will happily mark the answer +1.
Thanx in advance

Complete code:

```
<?php
include 'includes/db_connection.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO student (firstname) VALUES ('$firstname')";

$res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
if ($res1) {
echo 'succ';
//    header("Location: successful_message.php");
} else {
echo 'fail';
//    header("Location: valid_test.php");
}
} else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/css/formValidation.min.css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/ecmascript"></script>

  <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="contactForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
          <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
<?php } ?>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {



    $('#contactForm')
            .formValidation({
              framework: 'bootstrap',
              icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
              },
              fields: {
                firstname: {
                  validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                      message: 'The first name is required'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                      message: 'Name only contains Letter',
                      regexp: /^[A-Z a-z]*$/
                    }
                  }
                },


              }

            });


  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Too vague to give a proper response, but maybe your form validation plugin disables the button when the form data is not valid to it's standards?

Comment: @phenxd
i am trying to insert simple one value in database.
Validation prevents me from entering any number but when i submit, i faces the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with your specific form validation library. [According to the FormValidation.io FAQ](http://formvalidation.io/examples/cant-submit-form-after-validation/#the-submit-buttons-name-is-not-valid) they do not allow naming the submit button "submit". You should just be able to change the name attribute of your submit button.

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="notNamedSubmit">Submit</button>
```

You'll also have to update your PHP to look at the new name of the button instead of $_POST['submit'].

Comment: thanxxxxxxxxxxx alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two things that don't seem correct here. One, the HTML for your form does not appear compatible with JQuery's `validate`, and I think you need to be using `.validate` not `.formValidation`, which I'm not even sure if exists...

I would suggest formating your HTML as:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now, your JS could be as simple as:

```
$("#contactForm").validate();
```

..and work, but you could easily add extra validation through:

```
$("#contactForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        /*
            Add validation here
        */
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

There are many different validation settings that can be used, but I was just able to find this by googling it, I didn't know any of this before. My suggestion: do some research on these JQuery functions before coming here for answers. [**Here**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) is somewhere you can start.

Comment: By the way, you don't need `$(document).ready` in inline script, it won't execute until your "document is ready" already.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a delay caused by slow connections to cdn networks , try hosting all the libraries locally ( after all they're not that big of a file ).
I've seen that you followed the sample code presented in the libarary's documentation. I don't think this is a code related issue.

Comment: Abbasi
From where i would have to download all these libraries?